# How do I set a controller for my homepage

Tags: routes, controller

How can I set a controller for the homepage? I can't seem to find any way to override the default route to the homepage. I need to call an action from the homepage and can't find any examples of this can be done.

I have a matrixfield with entries in them and want to filter out the matrix blocks that have expired entries on the homepage.

Comment: So you just want to show all non-expired entries on your homepage? Can you be more specific? I'm guessing that you don't need a plugin for what you are trying to achieve here. I could be wrong of course, I would need some more information.

Comment: Yes, the problem is, if there's a block that contains an entry, it will show up regardless of if the entry has since expired and thus be empty. (The blocks only contain a single entry, i'm using a matrix simply so that the entries order can be sorted manually with the drag and drop feature of the matrix field)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe you can check if the entry in the matrix block is still valid (non-expired) and if that's not the case, just don't render the matrix block? Put everything in a simple if statement?

Something like this (hasn't been tested, use it as an example of what the actual code would be):

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
    {% if block.type == "something" %}
        {% if block.entry.status != 'expired' %}
            {{ block.entry.title}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but the thing I didn't mention is that I am then passing the blocks to a twig macro in sections, so the first 6 entries, then a special other entry, then the next 6. So that logic didn't quite work for me. But I did find another approach that does work using relatedTo:

<code>
{% for block in entry.homepageTiles %}
                    {% set relatedEntries = relatedEntries|merge(craft.entries.section('events, offers, branches, articles, twitter').relatedTo(block)) %}
                {% endfor %}